# Add custom item in Flutter GridView builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a new custom Button in gridview.builder. In my gridview, I have 5 items please see the image
[image]

please look at my simple code.

```
 GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3),
                        itemCount: _categoryList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (_categoryList.length != 0) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_categoryList[index].icon,),
                                  ),
                            );
                          } else
                            return Container();
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the child you can ask for index == 5 and show a Button-Widget instead of Photo-List-Item:

```
GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3),
                    itemCount: _categoryList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (_categoryList.length != 0) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: index == 5 ? myButton() : CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_categoryList[index].icon,),
                              ),
                        );
                      } else
                        return Container();
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Upon trying this it has error